# Pandas- Reshaping dataframe and Groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My dataframe look like this,

```
    loc         prod   period   qty        
0   Customer10  FG1    2483  200.000000    
1   Customer10  FG1    2484  220.000000    
2   Customer10  FG1    2485  240.000000    
3   Customer10  FG1    2486  260.000000      
4   Customer11  FG1    2483  300.000000    
5   Customer11  FG1    2484  320.000000    
6   Customer11  FG1    2485  340.000000    
7   Customer11  FG1    2486  360.000000    
8   Customer12  FG1    2483  400.000000    
9   Customer12  FG1    2484  420.000000    
10  Customer12  FG1    2485  440.000000    
11  Customer12  FG1    2486  460.000000    
12  Customer13  FG1    2483  500.000000    
13  Customer13  FG1    2484  520.000000    
14  Customer13  FG1    2485  540.000000    
15  Customer13  FG1    2486  560.000000    
16   Customer9  FG1    2483  100.000000    
17   Customer9  FG1    2484  120.000000    
18   Customer9  FG1    2485  140.000000    
19   Customer9  FG1    2486  160.000000
```

I want to reshape dataframe (distinct period as columns and prod as rows)
and groupby period, loc
Expected O/P

```
          2483    2484   2485    2486 
    FG1   1500    1580    1660   1740
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [37]: df.pivot_table(index='prod', columns='period', values='qty', aggfunc='sum')
Out[37]:
period    2483    2484    2485    2486
prod
FG1     1500.0  1600.0  1700.0  1800.0
```

or

```
In [39]: df.groupby(['prod','period'])['qty'].sum().unstack()
Out[39]:
period    2483    2484    2485    2486
prod
FG1     1500.0  1600.0  1700.0  1800.0
```

**UPDATE:**

> how to get period of max(qty)?

```
In [69]: pvt = df.pivot_table(index='prod', columns='period', values='qty', aggfunc='sum')

In [70]: pvt
Out[70]:
period    2483    2484    2485    2486
prod
FG1     1500.0  1600.0  1700.0  1800.0

In [71]: pvt.idxmax(axis=1)
Out[71]:
prod
FG1    2486
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @NikhilPola, you mean from the original DF or from the pivoted one?

Comment: am trying to calculate mean for above df --     df = pd.DataFrame(list(Demands), columns=['loc', 'prod', 'period', 'qty']).groupby(['period'])['qty'].mean()
but getting error ' No Numeric types found' ?

Comment: @NikhilPola, your question has been answered. If you want to ask another question please open a new question...